# tkinter - pass event to a function

Tags: python, tkinter

When I do

```
def popup(event):
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
```

'event' get highlighted by PyCharm and processed ok by python.
When I do

```
something.bind("<SomeKey>", foo(event,bar,INSERT))
```

'event' is not highlighted, and I get exception:

```
NameError: name 'event' is not defined
```

How are these two different? If python found event implicitly in first case, why it cannot do the same again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `bind`, you must give it a reference to something that can be called at a later time. You are not doing that -- you are calling `foo` *at the time you are calling `bind`*. Because you are calling the function, at that time the variable `event` doesn't exist, so you get the error.

The best thing to do is to define `foo` such that you don't need to pass it arguments. It's not best in a general sense per se, just best for when you are first learning Tkinter. Since tkinter automatically passes an event object, you need for it to accept that argument, but you don't need to pass that argument explicitly.

For example:

```
def foo(event):
    global bar
    <do something with event, bar and INSERT>

something.bind("<SomeKey>", foo)
```

Notice that there are no extra parenthesis in the `bind` statement. The `foo` *function* is passed to the `bind` command, and tkinter will automatically include an event object when it calls `foo`.